# Add data to new column based on previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df
     type  content
1    task   buy xbox
2    task   buy fruit from supermarket
3    note   orange with squash\buy if cheap
4    note   apple
5    task   buy sunglassess
```

The notes refer to the task directly above it. How could I manipulate the df to get the following df?
Expected Output:

```
         task                       comment1             comment2
1     buy xbox
2     buy fruit from supermarket   orange with squash     apple
                                   buy if cheap
3     buy sunglassess
...
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?  please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use helper `Series` for get groups by `task` by compare value with cumulkative sum, get counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
s = df['type'].eq('task').cumsum()
g = df.groupby(s).cumcount()

df1 = (df.set_index([s, g])['content']
         .unstack(fill_value='')
         .add_prefix('comment')
         .rename(columns={'comment0':'task'})
         .reset_index(drop=True))
         
print (df1)
                         task                        comment1 comment2
0                    buy xbox                                         
1  buy fruit from supermarket  orange with squasuy if cheap    apple
2             buy sunglassess
```

Comment: Thanks. If I have a date column in the original df, is there a way to get the task's date in the final output. I tried ```df.set_index([s, g, 'date'])...``` but that didn't work.

Comment: @asd - One idea - `df.set_index(['date', s, g])`

Comment: Thanks. Only tasks have a date. A note affiliated with a task doesn't have a date so changing the set index led to 2 rows per task to allow for the fact that a note doesn't have a date. I tried adding ```level="type"``` too.